# Tizen gear web app, launch web app with text data

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I have a watch face that launches another app using the code below:

```
var appId ="aGbGC3smHe.apptwo"; // app to be launched 

tizen.application.launch(appId);
```

It works, but I want to send text from the watch face to the second app and have the second app do something with it like below

```
if (senttext === "hello"){
console.log("hello")
}
```

I saw this code which I think might be half the answer but I dont know how to deal with the text at the other end....

```
var appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/share",null,"text/*",null ,[new tizen.ApplicationControlData("text", [message])]);

tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, null,function()console.log("launch application control succeed");
},function(e) {alert("ERROR")});
```

can I please know how to do this in Tizen Web? ... Thank you :)

Comment: What's the status right now? Did you try my solution?

Comment: Sorry, yes... had to change it very slightly just with the text display aspect of the code, but the rest worked.. Thank you so much! :) have been trying to get this to work for awhile!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the steps below:

1. Use the code below in the Watch Application(Watch face app)

```js
var obj = new tizen.ApplicationControlData("Paste_Your_Watch_Face_APP_ID_Here", ["Hello"]);

var obj1 = new tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/default",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    [obj] );
        
tizen.application.launchAppControl(obj1,
    "aGbGC3smHe.apptwo",
    function() {console.log("Launch Service succeeded"); },
    function(e) {console.log("Launch Service failed : " + e.message);},
    null);
```

2. Use the code below in the second app. Now, if you click on the word "Basic" it'll show the data sent from the Watch App.

```js
    var mainPage = document.querySelector('#main');

    mainPage.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');

        var reqAppControl = tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().getRequestedAppControl();

        if (reqAppControl) {
         var reqData = reqAppControl.appControl.data;
         for (var i = 0; i < reqData.length; i++) {
                console.log("#" + i + " key:" + reqData[i].key);
                for (var j = 0; j < reqData[i].value.length; j++) {
                   console.log("   value#" + j + ":"+reqData[i].value[j]);
                   // Process the data
                   contentText.innerHTML = reqData[i].value[j];
                }
       }
            
        }
        
    });
```

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! :)